# Power shell command to copy files from exactly 7 days older folder

Tags: powershell

I manually create folder in yyyyMMdd format on every Tuesday.

I wand a powershell or cmd command to create the folder and copy files from exact 7 days old folder to the current one

I tried below to get the folder, but it gives list of all the folders and files:

```
Get-childitem -path c:\temp | where { $_.Lastmodifiedtime -le (get-date).adddays(-7)}
```

Comment: Hi Welcome to stack overflow. I suggest you to try to build a bash script your self and when you feel stuck post your script and explain what problem you are facing.Happy scripting.

Comment: @RoadRunner Switch out `bash` for `powershell` and his point still stands. That said, to @Aks - update your question to include the code you've tried and details on what errors you get or how the result differ from what you expected.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the help file, you'll see that their are other switches you can use.
So, this to get only the directories:

```
Get-childitem -path c:\temp -Directory | 
where { $_.Lastmodifiedtime -le (get-date).adddays(-7)}
```

Lastly, there is no property called Lastmodifiedtime:

```
 Get-childitem -path D:\temp -Directory

<#
# Results

    Directory: D:\temp


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                                                      
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                                                      
d-----        17-Mar-20     23:48                AddressFiles                                                                                                                              
d-----        17-Feb-20     15:50                est                                                                                                                                       
d-----        14-Mar-20     17:03                here 
...
#>

Get-childitem -path 'D:\temp' -Directory | 
where { $_.LastWriteTime -le (get-date).adddays(-7)}

<#
# Results

    Directory: D:\temp


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                                                      
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                                                      
d-----        17-Mar-20     23:48                AddressFiles                                                                                                                              
d-----        17-Feb-20     15:50                est                                                                                                                                       
d-----        14-Mar-20     17:03                here 
...
#>
```

As shown, it's LastWriteTime. A write is a modification. You can only get what is available on an object. Note, other UI's can represent a field by another name.

```
Get-childitem -path D:\temp -Directory | 
Select-Object -First 1 | 
Get-Member -MemberType Properties -Force

<#
# Results

   TypeName: System.IO.DirectoryInfo

Name              MemberType     Definition                                                                                                                                                
----              ----------     ----------                                                                                                                                                
LinkType          CodeProperty   System.String LinkType{get=GetLinkType;}                                                                                                                  
Mode              CodeProperty   System.String Mode{get=Mode;}                                                                                                                             
pstypenames       CodeProperty   System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] pstypenames{g...
Target            CodeProperty   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] Target{get=GetTa...
PSChildName       NoteProperty   string PSChildName=AddressFiles                                                                                                                           
PSDrive           NoteProperty   PSDriveInfo PSDrive=D                                                                                                                                     
PSIsContainer     NoteProperty   bool PSIsContainer=True                                                                                                                                   
PSParentPath      NoteProperty   string PSParentPath=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::D:\temp                                                                                         
PSPath            NoteProperty   string PSPath=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::D:\temp\AddressFiles                                                                                  
PSProvider        NoteProperty   ProviderInfo PSProvider=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem                                                                                              
Attributes        Property       System.IO.FileAttributes Attributes {get;set;}                                                                                                            
CreationTime      Property       datetime CreationTime {get;set;}                                                                                                                          
CreationTimeUtc   Property       datetime CreationTimeUtc {get;set;}                                                                                                                       
Exists            Property       bool Exists {get;}                                                                                                                                        
Extension         Property       string Extension {get;}                                                                                                                                   
FullName          Property       string FullName {get;}                                                                                                                                    

***********************************************************************
LastAccessTime    Property       datetime LastAccessTime {get;set;}   *                                                                                                                    
LastAccessTimeUtc Property       datetime LastAccessTimeUtc {get;set;}*                                                                                                                   
LastWriteTime     Property       datetime LastWriteTime {get;set;}    *                                                                                                                     
LastWriteTimeUtc  Property       datetime LastWriteTimeUtc {get;set;} * 
***********************************************************************                                                                                                                   

Name              Property       string Name {get;}                                                                                                                                        
Parent            Property       System.IO.DirectoryInfo Parent {get;}                                                                                                                     
Root              Property       System.IO.DirectoryInfo Root {get;}                                                                                                                       
BaseName          ScriptProperty System.Object BaseName {get=$this.Name;}  
#>

Get-childitem -path D:\temp -Directory | 
Select-Object -Property '*' |
Select-Object -First 1

<#
# Results

PSPath            : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::D:\temp\AddressFiles
PSParentPath      : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::D:\temp
PSChildName       : AddressFiles
PSDrive           : D
PSProvider        : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem
PSIsContainer     : True
Mode              : d-----
BaseName          : AddressFiles
Target            : {}
LinkType          : 
Name              : AddressFiles
FullName          : D:\temp\AddressFiles
Parent            : temp
Exists            : True
Root              : D:\
Extension         : 
CreationTime      : 17-Mar-20 23:46:03
CreationTimeUtc   : 18-Mar-20 06:46:03

****************************************
LastAccessTime    : 17-Mar-20 23:48:15 *
LastAccessTimeUtc : 18-Mar-20 06:48:15 *
LastWriteTime     : 17-Mar-20 23:48:15 *
LastWriteTimeUtc  : 18-Mar-20 06       *
****************************************
#>
```

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions.

Comment: How is this currently off-topic? The OP, gave specific request with a code sample --- "I tried below to get the folder, but it gives list of all the folders and files:
Get-childitem -path c:\temp | where { $_.Lastmodifiedtime -le (get-date).adddays(-7)}"  Which is the only part I provided an answer for.